# How to have one observable function for three buttons in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a button linked to an observable event. The button just uploads an excel spreadsheet and then loads it as a dataframe. I have three of these buttons. Each does the same thing. I would like to create a function that does the uploading so that I dont have to define it two separate times. I just cant figure out how to create a function that allows me to do this in Shiny.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("My button issue"),

        mainPanel(
            box(status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,collapsible = T,collapsed=FALSE,title = "A. Upload data",
                fileInput("pathology",label="",multiple = FALSE),br()),
            box(status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,collapsible = T,collapsed=FALSE,title = "B. Upload data",
                fileInput("FileIn_endoscopy",label="",multiple = FALSE),br())

        )

)

server <- function(input, output) {
    observe({
        inFile_path <- input$pathology
        if (!is.null(inFile_path)) {   
            dataFile <- read_excel(inFile_path$datapath, sheet=1)
            RV2$data<-data.frame(dataFile, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
            enable("textPrepPath")
        }
        else{disable("textPrepPath")}
    })

    observe({
        inFile_endoscopy <- input$FileIn_endoscopy
        if (!is.null(inFile_endoscopy)) {   
            dataFile <- read_excel(inFile_endoscopy$datapath, sheet=1)
            RV$data<-data.frame(dataFile, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
            enable("textPrep")
        }
        else{disable("textPrep")}
    })


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I can't install EndoMineR, is this package the one you use?

Comment: @bretauv the EndoMineR package isnt really needed here. It can be removed from the code as long as the datafile becomes a dataframe. Ill change the code

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience with shiny modules, but I think it's a good approach here. Your example code is incomplete so I can't test it, but maybe something like this whould work?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(readxl)

fileButton <- function(id, title) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    box(status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,collapsible = T,collapsed=FALSE,title = title,
        fileInput(ns("inputfile"),label="",multiple = FALSE),br())
  )
}

file <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$inputfile, {
    inFile_path <- input$inputfile
    if (!is.null(inFile_path)) {   
      dataFile <- read_excel(inFile_path$datapath, sheet=1)
      RV2$data<-data.frame(dataFile, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      enable("textPrepPath")
    }
    else{disable("textPrepPath")}
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My button issue"),
  mainPanel(
    fileButton("pathology", "A. Upload data"),
    fileButton("FileIn_endoscopy", "B. Upload data")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  callModule(file, "pathology")
  callModule(file, "FileIn_endoscopy")
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks @motch. I thought modules might be the way to go but always struggled to understand them fully. Just a quick further question- In the file function I am supposed to output to a different dataframe for each callModule (first is RV$data and the second is RV2$data. Also I want to disable different buttons in each module (textPrepPath and textPrep). How do I add these variables to the function?